# Given the following summation is there a way to combine given the following orientation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation, power-series, summation-method

I have the following summation: \begin{equation}\sum_{n=2}^\infty c_n(n)(n-1)(x-1)^{n-2}+(x+1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(x-1)^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(x-1)^{n-1}+(x+1)^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-1)^n +2(x-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-1)^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-1)^n \end{equation}
**Note the incline is bad on this post I will try to fix, after I post it buts just one large sum.**
$$\newcommand{\sm}[2]{\sum_{#1}^{#2}}$$
I managed to combine them using [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676295/is-sum-n-1-infty-nc-nx-1n-equivalent-to-sum-n-0-infty-nc-nx-1n).

Which I managed to convert to the following:
\begin{equation}\sm{k=0}{\infty}(c_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)+kc_k+(k+1)c_{k+1}+c_k)(x-1)^k+ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{\sm{n=0}{\infty}c_n(x-1)^{n+2}+\sm{n=0}{\infty}2c_n(x-1)^{n+1}} \end{equation}
What's left is these two odd balls as I call them. I am trying to combine them into that nice summation with k, because the work is for a power series solution to a DE. My question is, is there a method to combine them.

Comment: Is the top equation of my post readable I am trying to make have a scroll bar so it can read linearly, and not wrap?

Comment: It looks good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$l=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x-1)^{n+2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2c_n(x-1)^{n+1}$$
Rewrite this part as:
$$l=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}c_{n-2}(x-1)^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2c_{n-1}(x-1)^{n}$$
$$l=2c_0(x-1)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}c_{n-2}(x-1)^{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2c_{n-1}(x-1)^{n}$$
$$l=2c_0(x-1)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(c_{n-2}+2c_{n-1})(x-1)^{n}$$
Then start all the others sums at indice $n=2$

Comment: Is it math legal to set each piece of the summation equal to zero? if I add what you have to what I have and set $c_0=0$, and $c_2+2c_1=0$, and my part?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. But collect all the terms with the same power of $x-1$ and set them equal to zero. @EnlightenedFunky

Comment: You should end with some constants and also with a term with $(x-1)$ set these coefficients and the constants equal to zero @EnlightenedFunky

Comment: Question is how did you learn to manipulate it like that I assumed that everything would boil down in a pretty format to solve. Since its for first year course in DE.

Comment: It comes with practise ..you will surely end with a nice solution yes. @EnlightenedFunky